# Using smart pointers as global variables

Tags: c++, c++11, global-variables, smart-pointers

Let's say I have a program in which I must use a global variable (of some class type).

I would like to be able to use smart pointers so I won't have to worry about deleting it.

in some file `Common.hpp` file I have the declaration:

```
extern unique_ptr<CommandBuffer> globalCommandBuffer;
```

and in my main.cpp:

```
#include "Common.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {   
   globalCommandBuffer(new CommandBuffer());
}
```

this creates many compilation errors. so obviously I'm doing it wrong.

my questions are:

- is it a good design choice to use smart pointers for global variables?
- if so, what is the correct way of doing so?
- which smart pointer is preferable?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a pointer rather than just a plain variable?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to have global variables, no matter the type. As for your use of smart pointers, you should not really think of them as simply self-deleting pointers, instead think of them from a resource *ownership* perspective: Can a resource have a single owner at a time, or multiple simultaneous owners. Also, due to the semantics of `std::unique_ptr` it really doesn't make much sense to have it as a global variable type, it's meant to be passed around as an argument.

Comment: @Galik
no.
but I could not figure how to initialize my variable without using dynamic allocation

Comment: @EladMaimoni If you don't need dynamic allocation then I would avoid it, just figure out the syntax how to initialize (most references/tutorials should cover that)..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want either:

```
globalCommandBuffer.reset(new CommandBuffer());
```

Or:

```
globalCommandBuffer = std::make_unique<CommandBuffer>();
```

Global variables are very rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 8):

If you want a global (you probably don't, but just in case you do), just create a global. The whole point of a smart pointer is to manage ownership and lifetime. In the case of a global, those are generally quite trivial--you want them to exist before anything else happens, and continue existing until everything else quits happening.

Unless you need something different from that, just create your object as a global object, not a smart pointer to a dynamically allocated object.

Answer (score -3):

Problem is not with global variable which is some smart_ptr but problem is the fact that you are defining it once in header file - and again in main.cpp. Double definitions would definitely be problematic.

Comment: The header in the OP does not contain any definitions.